# Ckeditor 4 Ckfinder 3 Integration in PHP

Tags: php, ckeditor, integration, ckfinder

I was not able to upgrade Ckeditor 3 with Ckfinder 2 to Ckeditor 4 with Ckfinder 3.

Can anybody please to recommend me a tested stuff to learn how to do this task?

Comment: What is the error? Where is your code ?

Comment: Could you please describe in details what doesn't work?
You may find this article helpful: http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

I could integrate ckeditor 4 with ckfinder 3 making the following actions:
1. in xampp\php\php.ini 
Line ;extension=php_fileinfo I deleted ; from the beginning of the line
2. in ckfinder/config.php I did:

```
functioncheckAuthentication()
{
return true;
}
```

In order to get buttons Text color; Background color, I downloaded Full Package for Ckeditor 4.5.5